# JQuery: How stop an animation loop on mouse over? (Object Oriented)

Tags: jquery

I have defined an object that displays a slideshow, below is a simplified version of the render method.

My problem is that I want to stop all the animations running on the startLoop method. But I'm not figuring it out.

```
// Render display
this.render = function() {

   ...
   MAKE HTML WITH SLIDESHOW
   ...

   // Start the loop
   this.startLoop();

   // Stop on hover
   $('#display' + this.id).hover(function() {
      this.animate.stop(); // Doesn't work
   }, function() {
      // Here should continue the animation
   });

}

// Loop Slides
this.startLoop = function() {
   ...
   ANIMATIONS HERE
   ...
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You've oversimplified the code.  What is in `startLoop`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got an answer. It has to do with the scope of the function you're calling, you should use `$.proxy`. [More information here.](http://jimmycuadra.com/posts/understanding-jquery-14s-proxy-method)

The function was changed to something like:

```
// Stop on hover
$('#display' + this.id).hover($.proxy(this, 'stopAnimation'));
```

Where `this` inside the `$.proxy` is the scope (my object) and `stopAnimation` is a method from the object.

Hope this helps someone out there. Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer to help guide people in the future.

Answer (score 2):

"this" references the HTML Element and not the jQuery object in the .hover callback function, you need to get the jQuery object for "this", It should be $( this ) as show below:

```
// Stop on hover
   $('#display' + this.id).hover(function() {
      $(this).animate.stop(); // Doesn't work
   }, function() {
      // Here should continue the animation
   });
```

Comment: Hi Kory, I tried that, but when I do a mouse over, I get the following error on my JavaScript console: Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b,c,d){function g(){e.queue===!1&&f._mark(this);var b=f.extend({},e),c=this.nodeType===1,d=c&&f(this).........

Comment: And if I add this: alert($(this).id); inside the hover function, I get "undefined", which means that I can't get to my object inside the function.

Comment: What do you get for alert( this ); and for alert( $(this) ); ?

Comment: I think you changed the wrong "this" to be $(this) you don't need the ".id" in the alert, because we are talking about the last"this" in your code.